# SSRS 2008 Time Conversion within IIF Statement

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to convert a time within an `IIF` statement.

I have a field with a value of:  `2013-10-15 01:00:00.0000000`.  I am trying to convert that to "01:00" and then produce 1 of 2 results based on the conversion.

I have tried both using a `case when` statement which does not seem to work.

I have also tried using `like "*01:00*"` which also does not work.  Currently, this is what I'm attempting to do, but it seem that I'm not going about this the right way:

```
=iif(Fields!TEST1.VALUE LIKE ("*01:00:00.0000000*"), "TRUE", "NOT TRUE")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking strictly at what you're trying to do, with an SSRS expression you need to use `InStr` to check for a substring in a larger string:

```
=IIf(InStr(Fields!TEST1.Value, "01:00:") > 0, True, False)
```

This works fine on your example row and another test case:

[image]

However, we know very little about your data - is the underlying data actually a string or a datetime?

If your data is datetime, you can use a different approach:

```
=IIf(Hour(Fields!TEST1.Value) = 1 and Minute(Fields!TEST1.Value) = 0
    , True
    , False)
```

Or even:

```
=IIf(Fields!TEST1.Value.ToString("HH:mm") = "01:00"
    , True
    , False)
```

If possible, I would consider datetime functions if at all possible as they are closest to the intent of what you seem to be trying to achieve.